# Java - JDBC MySQL connection issue

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to establish a connection but for some reason I am having issues doing so.

I think it may be a syntax error - but I am not completely sure. I have commented out numerous syntax approaches I have tried. I used MySQL documentation for help, even when following their syntax i get problems.

When I run the code without the Connection the program jumps into the try. But as soon as I add the Connection code it jumps to the catch section of the code - therefore there must be an issue with the syntax.

Can anyone spot where I have gone wrong? Thank You in advance.

```
public void selectData()
{

    try 
    {   
        Connection con = null;

        //Accessing driver from the JAR file
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc"); 

        //String a = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/c3361434?profileSQL=true";

        ///String a = "jdbc:mysql://address=(protocol=tcp)(host=localhost)(port=3306)(user=root)(password=root)/c3361434";

        //Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://address=(protocol=tcp)(host=localhost)(port=3306)(user=root)/c3361434"); 

        //Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/c3361434", "root", "root");

        //con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/c3361434?" + "user=root&password=root");

        Output3.setText("Connection has been established");

        /*
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM RSA-data");

        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

        while(result.next())
        {
            Output2.setText(result.getString(1));
            Output3.setText("in the while loop");
        }
        */

    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Output4.setText("db fail");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the stacktrace please?

Comment: How are you running this? Do you have the MySQL JDBC driver JAR in the classpath?

Comment: @MickMnemonic is correct. You do not have your JAR installed correctly. `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc")` simply tests whether you have the JDBC driver correctly imported into your application.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

Check if you mysql is running, in command line type:

```
mysqld --install
```

In java source:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDB?dontTrackOpenResources=true");
```

Comment: I am running using xamp from my usb, this should not be a problem... i tried the command line - mysqld is not recognised. I have added the java code recommended how ever I get the same output "db fail".

Answer (score 0):

the command mysqld not reconized because you need to enter at path specific.
For example:

MS - DOS:

```
cd C:/MySQL/bin

C:/MySQL/bin>mysqld --install
```

Into folder bin there is the mysqld.exe

Do you got it ?